# User account merge request - Two different profiles created

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I asked a question few days back for which I was awarded reputation points and badge.

However, at that time the account was not created.

Today I asked one more question. For which I earned reputation points and medal. The profile got created using Google OpenID.

However, the reputation points does not add up and show.

Answer (score 3):

Please find your previous post and flag it for moderator attention, asking that they merge it with your new account.